# Creating a matrix from the data inside the csv

Tags: python, csv, linear-regression

I'm reading a CSV-file (data is comma separated), appending the two columns inside this file into two different arrays named 'x_train' and 'y_train'. The problem is that I can't manage to form the data the way I wanted to. So, to summarise; I want each entry for row[0] to be appended in x_train and row[1] for y_train.

```py
import numpy as np
import csv

x_train = []
y_train = []

with open("length_weight.csv",  newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
    for row in reader:
        x_train.append(row[0])
        y_train.append(row[1])

x_train = np.mat(x_train)
y_train = np.mat(y_train)
```

---

A small portion of the CSV-file

```
8.070000000000000284e+01,1.126768031895251987e+01
8.040000000000000568e+01,1.195844519276935358e+01
7.250000000000000000e+01,8.317461617744008606e+00
1.030000000000000000e+02,1.880844309373589951e+01
1.075999999999999943e+02,1.947419293659330108e+01
7.940000000000000568e+01,9.877652348817933969e+00
8.190000000000000568e+01,1.127064360995226977e+01
1.015999999999999943e+02,1.640426417487080357e+01
1.085999999999999943e+02,1.749193091101176378e+01
```

Expected output:

```
[[1.12341234], [1,43214321], ...]
```

But actual output is:

```
[[1.12341234, 1.12341234, ...]]
```

Comment: Can you please provide an example of the CSV?

Comment: It's under the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need every number inside a list you can do it directly while appending in to `x_train` and `y_train`:

```
import numpy as np
import csv

x_train = []
y_train = []

with open("length_weight.csv",  newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
    for row in reader:
        x_train.append([row[0]])
        y_train.append([row[1]])
```

Comment: Hello, and thank you for the quick feedback. Somehow I was not able to see this. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If the problem in shape of resulting np.matrix, just reshape it with

```
x_train = np.mat(x_train).reshape(-1, 1)
y_train = np.mat(y_train).reshape(-1, 1)
```

See below

```
>>> np.mat(x_train)
matrix([[ 80.7,  80.4,  72.5, 103. , 107.6,  79.4,  81.9, 101.6, 108.6]])
>>> np.mat(x_train).reshape(-1, 1)
matrix([[ 80.7],
        [ 80.4],
        [ 72.5],
        [103. ],
        [107.6],
        [ 79.4],
        [ 81.9],
        [101.6],
        [108.6]])
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. This seems also to work well.